# Combining multiple Polygons into one MultiPolygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-processing, multipart, multi-polygon

QGIS 3.34.3 has a processing function "Multipart to singleparts". But what about the other way around? What is the easiest way to create a MultiPolygon from several polygons?

Comment: Also the "exact" opposite of "Multipart to singleparts" is actually "Promote to multipart" (which doesn't combine polygons, just make singlepolygons into multipolygons containing a single part) but I don't think that is what you meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

["Collect geometries"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#collect-geometries) processing algorithm is what you are looking for.

> Takes a vector layer and collects its geometries into new multipart geometries.
>
> One or more attributes can be specified to collect only geometries belonging to the same class (having the same value for the specified attributes), alternatively all geometries can be collected.
>
> All output geometries will be converted to multi geometries, even those with just a single part. This algorithm does not dissolve overlapping geometries - they will be collected together without modifying the shape of each geometry part.

Comment: That is absolutely right... I've just found that out too. My problem was that I had the "Edit features In-Place" switch activated in the toolbox. Another option would be using the `ST_Collect` function in DB-Manager.

Comment: Yes, ST_Collect is equivalent to this processing tool. they are the same just used at different places and maybe coded a bit differently